# Broken LVM Physical volume after resizing partition

Tags: partition, lvm, luks, migration

I bought a new larger SSD to replace my old one. The old one has 3 partitions, 2 for booting and a third (last) one with LVM2 on LUKS. I did the following to migrate:

- **dd** the contents of the old drive to the new one (**bs=4M**)
- Run **partprobe** on the new drive (it complained that "Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space")
- I used **gdisk** -> extra functionality -> "relocate backup data structures to the end of the disk"
- At this point, if I opened the partition with cryptsetup, LVM worked fine
- I then resized the third partition with **GParted** (when I tried to use the whole disk it threw an error that I can't resize it past the size of the disk, so I had to make it 2 MiB smaller than what GParted showed)
- I then opened the now larger partition with **cryptsetup** and for some reason LVM doesn't detect the LVM physical volume anymore.

Running **lvmdiskscan -v**:

> ..
>   /dev/mapper/crypt_ssd    [930,76 GiB] LVM physical volume
>   ..

Running **pvdisplay /dev/mapper/crypt_ssd**

> Failed to find physical volume "/dev/mapper/crypt_ssd".

Where did I screw up? **lvscan** doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's weird that `lvmdiskscan` and `pvdisplay` disagree. Have you tried `vgscan` and `pvscan`? Have you removed the old drive? Because you used `dd` you copied the partition and filesystem IDs; it would not suprise me if that can lead to issues.